# Chaining operations with RxSwift

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I want to chain following operations

- createUserandVerify

  - Create Anonymous User (user)
  - Verify User -> verifiedUser
  - If verification successful return verifiedUser else return user
- Get stuff with coredata `getStuff`

  - If stuff.count > 0 Upload stuff with user credentials `uploadStuff`
- Finally report the result of all operations

I wrote createUserandVerify as below. I wonder how should I write `uploadStuff` in reactive way. Upload function depends on user credentials. Therefore It must only run after createUserandVerify. I know I could just check count of array inside `uploadStuff` and return empty but I wonder the best practices.

```
func createUserandVerify() -> Single<User> {
    return Service.sharedInstance.generateAnonUser()
        .flatMap{ user in
            if Service.sharedInstance.isOldRegisteredUser {
                print("It is old user")
                // We need to verify the receipt
                return  Service.sharedInstance.verifyReceipt()
                    .flatMap { verifiedUser in
                        print("Returning Verified new user [Verification Success]")
                        return Single.just((verifiedUser))

                    }.catchError{ error ->Single<User> in
                        print("Returning firstly created user [Verification Failed]")
                        print("Error Type: \(error)")
                        return Single.just(user)

                }
            } else {
                //Normal anonymous old user
                print("Returning firstly created user [Anonymous]")
                return Single.just(user)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your code for `uploadStuff`

Comment: and your implementation for `getStuff`

Comment: `getStuff` gets array of Stuff and `uploadStuff` sends a request to Server and gets a Single<String> as a result. I just wanna know how to chain them so pseudo code is OK. My concerns are, running upload function only after createUserandVerify succeeds and only running upload if array isn't empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions (since I have not worked with `Single` I changed them to `Observable`):

```
func createUserandVerify() -> Observable<User>
func getStuff() -> [Stuff]
func uploadStuff(_ user: User) -> Observable<String>
```

`createUserandVerify()` should publish errors with `onError` so `uploadStuff` will not be called if something goes wrong.

Possible solution:

```
enum CustomError: Error {
    case instanceMissing
    case notEnoughStuff
}

createUserandVerify()
    .flatMap { [weak self] (user) -> Observable<String> in
        guard let strongSelf = self else { throw CustomError.instanceMissing }
        guard strongSelf.getStuff().count > 0 else { throw CustomError.notEnoughStuff }
        return strongSelf.uploadStuff(user)
    }
    .subscribe(
        onNext: { stringResult in
          // print result from 'uploadStuff'
          print(stringResult)
    },
        onError: { error in
          // will be reached if something goes
          // wrong in 'createUserandVerify' or 'uploadStuff'
          // or if one of your custom errors in 'flatMap' are thrown
          print(error)
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

You could also make `getStuff` reactive by returning an `Observable` or `Single` and also include it in the chain via `flatMap`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was thinking about using some operators like filter, concat etc. Something like this, if user is created, program can continue and uploadStuff. Something like two observables? I am new to Rxswift maybe something like using `share` of user and another observable for uploading stuff. I guess I will use flatMap. Thanks once again for taking your time to write detailed answer. I appreciate it.